# Multithreaded printf vs write(2) buffering

Tags: solaris, c, io, printf, multithreading

Consider the following piece of code running under Solaris 11.3:

```
void *run(void *args) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("Line #%d printed by child\n", i + 1);
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t tid;
  int ret = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, run, NULL);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("Line #%d printed by parent\n", i + 1);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Upon running, the parent thread always prints out all of its lines before the newly created thread. Some might say that `pthread_create` is just too slow to allow the other thread to even start its job before the main thread returns. However, swapping out `printf` for `write(2)` produces 
the expected output where the threads occasionally take turns printing their lines.

How could this behaviour be explained?

Buffering certainly has nothing to do with it since terminal output is line-buffered by default; it should be true for both `write` and `printf`.

Even if the functions use some sort of a blocking techique to provide thread-safety, what exactly would prevent the output from scrambling?

Comment: It _is_ a buffering issue.  You're confusing `write(2)` with `fwrite(3)`.  `write(2)` is a low-level function and is unbuffered.  `fwrite(3)` is a `stdio` function and is buffered by default.  You get that effect because `stdout` gets block-buffered in the background thread, while it remains line-buffered in the parent.  Add `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` to both threads and compare.

Comment: The output of the other thread still goes to a terminal, so shouldn't it be line-buffered as usual?

Comment: "Line buffering" is an aspect of `stdio`, not "terminal".  `write(2)` does not use `stdio` and so is not buffered.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: it's not a buffereing issue, as both threads are writing to the same buffer.  Each call to `printf` will acquire the lock on `stdout` then write the line (which will flush if linebuffered, but not if not), then release the lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is eniterly due to speed.  If you put a call to `usleep` between the `pthread_create` and the loop, and tune the value a bit, you can get it to mix some of the lines.

Note that due to stdio locking, once one thread fails to acquire the lock on `stdout` once or twice, it is likely to sleep for a few milliseconds (which will allow the other thread to complete its loop), so you won't see a lot of mixing.  If you want more mixing, you'll need to put a `usleep` in the loop too.

On my machine a `usleep(50)` before the loop in the parent, and a `usleep(1)` in both loops will result in almost alternating lines.

Comment: `sched_yield` on my machine also enables the lines to alternate each time, which is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!